# OLAP, if dimension has 'unknown' member, then only it is displayed if no measures added. Any ways to fix it?

Tags: olap, msas

I have cube in Microsoft Analysis Services with several dimensionsions and measures.

When I(in cube browser, or through pivot tables in excel) try to drag dimension's attribute to grid with no measures added the following happens:

- if there were unknown member, then only it is displayed. Other rows from dimension are not displayed.
- if dimension had no unknown member, then everything from attribute is displayed.
- after dragging measures to grid, everything is displayed for dimension with unknown member as well.

Is it possible to change behaviour to display all rows for dimension even if it has unknown member?

Or I did miss something and having unknown member has nothing to do with number of rows being displaying from dimension when no measures are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It depends on measures orders.